# How can I move files using bash/for loop inside subdirectories?

Tags: bash

I have a folder where I have 20 of different extension files and Id like to move those files to 3 different folders. Now, how do I move all of those files (condtitions based on which they end up in the folders are not important atm) WITHOUT those 3 subdirectories assuming they already exists? 
At this moment I am stuck at putting those subfolders into themselves and obviously I dont want that so only files which are on the same levels as 3 subfolders Id like to put inside those 3 subf. Thank you!

Ps. If I focus on *.txt in for loop it tells me it cannot stat it so I am confused..

```
X
 |_A
 |_B
 |_C
 |_file1.ext
 |_file2.ext
 |_file3.ext
 .
 .
 .
 |_file20.ext
```

Comment: I can't get what you want to do, give us some examples please :)

Comment: `find  /path/to/folder  -name  \*.txt -exec cp -a {} /path/to/folder/you/want \;`  I hope I understood right your aim.

Comment: Thanks. What I want is to move all files from folder X to its subfolders (A,B and C).  Now since I'm doing "for i in *" it's trying to put folders A, B and C in themselves too so what I'm trying to say is that I don't know how to move only files  to folders A,B and C and leave A, B and C folders alone (IF they exist) under folder X . I hope that explains . Folder structure in original post. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options to exclude subdirectories:

1. since you want to move files with extensions, change `for i in *` to `for i in *.*` (this may be the simplest option, provided none of your subdirectory names contains a `.` character)
2. add an explicit test for the file type ex. `for i in *; do [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue; ...`
3. (similar to the above) use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ...`
4. switch to a shell that supports glob qualifiers such as zsh - where you can write `for f in *(.)` to loop over regular files only

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver! That was it plus I needed to get rid of some stuff I was doing unnecessarily.